# How can I remove the extra page in my document showing tabular[t]?

Tags: tables, thesis

I have written this simple code, but it gives me an extra front page which shows as given.

My Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis} 
\graphicspath{Figures/}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{vector} 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\frontmatter     
\title  {Title}
\authors  {\texorpdfstring
            {\href{hamimulhasan@gmail.com}{Hamimul Hasan}}
            \and
            {\href{imticore57@gmail.com}{Imtiaz Ahmed}}
            }
\addresses  {\groupname\\deptname\\\univname} 
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}
\setstretch{1.3} 
\fancyhead{}  
\rhead{\thepage}  
\lhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
```

[image]

Thesis.cls code for title page:

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{
\btypeout{Title Page}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
\hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
    \vfill
    {\huge \bf \@title \par}
    \vfill
    {\LARGE by \par}
    \smallskip
    {\LARGE \authornames \par}
    \vfill
    {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the \par}
    {\large degree of Doctor of Philosophy \par}
    \bigskip
    \bigskip
    {\large in the \par}
    {\large \facname \par}
    {\large \deptname \par}
    \bigskip
    \bigskip
    \bigskip
    {\Large \@date \par}
    \bigskip
  \end{center}
  \par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}%
\global\let\thanks\relax
\global\let\maketitle\relax
\global\let\@thanks\@empty
\global\let\@author\@empty
\global\let\@date\@empty
\global\let\@title\@empty
\global\let\title\relax
\global\let\author\relax
\global\let\date\relax
\global\let\and\relax
\cleardoublepage
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We don't have `Thesis.cls`, so it's essentially impossible to know what goes wrong. You're at least forgetting arguments to `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: Any class with the name  `Thesis`  seems to be cratched, not to mention that it is a really terrible name.

Comment: I appreciate you all for commenting. The Thesis.cls file is long, there is like 382 lines and the compiler does not show any error there, and also I am new in latex, so can you please elaborate that in which places I should be looking? Thank you

Comment: Search for `[t]` in your document, the error is around there, probably you miss a `\` or put an argument where is not allowed and TeX considers it like a plain text.

Comment: I have added the Thesis.cls code for the title page, now can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Download a newer version of the template and start over, you are doing the title page completely wrong. Or don't use a template at all. The one you are using is very bad, I know it for years and people have problems with that class en masse.

Comment: By the way, where did you get that template from?

Comment: Okay I will start from the scratch again. Thank you. The template was provided from Sharelatex. I came to work with Sharelatex two or three weeks earlier and I had some other deadlines, so I couldnt concentrate much. And thats why I used a template. Guess, I have to give it more time. do you have any good template to start with?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: I voted to close as unclear. The class code shown is irrelevant, as the titlepage is done manually in the main file. Also, the template is outdated, and bad.